# Connect MySQL through localhost not working but 127.0.0.1 is working

Tags: mysql, sockets, connection, localhost

**OS:** Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

**php version control :** phpbrew

**php version :** 5.5.10

I pinged localhost which resolved to 127.0.0.1.

This indicates that my host (/etc/hosts) file is correct.

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

Whenever I try connecting to MySQL using a php script like the one below it doesn't work and gives me the error: no such directory.

```
    //connect to the database
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","password") or die(mysql_error());
```

However, when I connect via 127.0.0.1 it will work

```
 //connect to the database
        mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","password") or die(mysql_error());
```

Additionally, my phpmyadmin does not work when logging in using "localhost" i had to change the file to add 127.0.0.1 option during log on.

How can I use localhost to connect to the MySQL database?

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. It's awful and is being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices. Always be absolutely **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will have severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Agreed. I am working with legacy code and was just migrating a server.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer to this problem was that in the my.cnf located within

```
/etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

the line was either

```
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

or

```
bind-address = localhost
```

it should have been

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

which will allow all connections

Comment: newbies note! this answer will open your site to attackers. far better off to set the connection 127.0.0.1 and require authorised users to connect via ssh.

Comment: @pgee70 totally agreed! If you do that, ensure that TCP port 3306 is forbidden for access from outside!

Comment: Downvote, 0.0.0.0 rely to all network interfaces (include public interface) so reliable to attack

Comment: Agreed, attaching the broadcast ip is not reliable as any ip could access your server

Answer (score 7):

PHP is still trying to use the default socket location. This problem can appear if you have **moved the MariaDB/MySQL folder** from */var/lib/mysql* to another location. In order to solve the problem you have to define the new socket's location in the */etc/php.ini* file.

```
mysqli.default_socket =/newDBLocation/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Watch out, depending on which driver you use, you may have to specify the *pdo_mysql.default_socket=*!

In order to check your current directory run the following command in mysql:

```
select @@datadir;
```

Comment: This solved my problem, in order to find which socket file mysql is using, I ran `mysqladmin variables | grep socket` command which was pointing to `/tmp/mysql.sock`. (OS X Sierra)

Answer (score 6):

In many cases `localhost` is a hint to use the UNIX socket to connect to the MySQL server process, where `127.0.0.1` forces a TCP connection. Sometimes the UNIX socket is in an unexpected place, or simply isn't accessible, which results in the "file not found" error.

The socket is typically something like `/tmp/mysql.sock` or could be in some other place depending on your distribution and how much you've customized it.

Keep in mind that access via UNIX socket, which is local to the server by definition, and TCP are controlled by two different rules. `localhost` in a `GRANT` refers to UNIX socket. `%` or some specific host name refers to remote via TCP.

Comment: Are there any references to this statement?