# What is "Connection refused" message for python code?

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, peewee

Here is my code,

```
import peewee
import sqlite3
import pymysql
import psycopg2

myDB=peewee.MySQLDatabase("new", host="localhost",port=3306, 
user="root", passwd="")
class MySQLModel(peewee.Model):
class Meta:
    database= myDB

class NewPost(MySQLModel):
   id=peewee.PrimaryKeyField()
   width=peewee.CharField()
   height=peewee.CharField()
   pixel=peewee.CharField()
   image=peewee.CharField()

myDB.connect()

if __name__ =='__main__':
     myDB.create_tables([NewPost])
```

I can't connect to database as I get the error that says:

> peewee.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on
>   'localhost' ([Errno 61] Connection refused)")

Comment: Check the mysql logs to see why the connection is refused.

Comment: Try `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19712307/1925257) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31413728/1925257).

Comment: [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.38 started; log sequence number 11559969      
[Note] RSA private key file not found: /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql56//private_key.pem. Some authentication plugins will not work.
RSA public key file not found: /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql56//public_key.pem. Some authentication plugins will not work.
[Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
[Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.38'  socket: '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 0  MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution.
first: I changed my database to PostgreSQL 
second : this is my code;

```
import psycopg2
import traceback
try:
con=psycopg2.connect(database="elin",user="elin", 
password="8981",host="127.0.0.1",port="5432")
cur=con.cursor()

cur.execute("""
 CREATE TABLE imageinf(
 img_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
 img_url VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
 );
 """)

con.commit()
print('Create the table DONE ')
con.close()
except psycopg2.Error as e:
print ('I am unable to connect to db')
print(e)
print(e.pgcode)
print(e.pgerror)
print(traceback.format_exc())
```