# Apache with Docker shows a [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server

Tags: php, mysql, apache, docker, dockerfile

I use Mac OSX and MAMP.
I wanted to make a Docker Container for a web project, because it uses a php 5.5 version, and i didn't want to make changes on my MAMP.
So here is the docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services:
    www:
        build: "./docker/apache"
        volumes:
          - .:/var/www
          - ./docker/silexx.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/silexx.conf
        working_dir: "/var/www"
        command : "bash -c 'source /etc/apache2/envvars; apache2 -DFOREGROUND'"
        ports:
          - 80:80
        links:
          - mysql

    mysql:
        image: mysql:5.7
        restart: always
        environment:
          MYSQL_DATABASE: 'silexx_dev'
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'root'
        ports:
          - 3306:3306

    pma:
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        environment:
         - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
        restart: always
        ports:
         - 8080:80
        volumes:
         - /sessions
```

This is the Dockerfile :

```
FROM  debian:jessie

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y --force-yes apt-transport-https apache2 php5 php5-cli libicu-dev php5-gd php5-curl php5-mysql php5-memcached php5-intl php5-json php5-mcrypt curl sudo
RUN a2enmod rewrite

# install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

RUN apt-get install -y --force-yes make git locales gcc g++
RUN echo "en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8" >> /etc/locale.gen
RUN locale-gen
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8

RUN rm /etc/apache2/sites-*/*
COPY default /etc/apache2/sites-available/default.conf
RUN a2ensite default

CMD "source /etc/apache2/envvars && apache2 -DFOREGROUND"
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8

CMD "/etc/init.d/mysql start"

# forward request and error logs to docker log collector
RUN ln -sf /proc/1/fd/1 /var/log/apache2/access.log
RUN ln -sf /proc/1/fd/2 /var/log/apache2/error.log

EXPOSE 80
```

And I made a little vhost :

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/core/"
    ServerName demo.silexx.local
    ServerAlias demo.silexx.local
    #ErrorLog "logs/silexx.com-error_log"
    #CustomLog "logs/silexx.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Then I make docker-compose up, I generate my containers.

When I go to the console and 
 mysql -h localhost -P 3306 --protocol=tcp -u root -proot

It works perfectely !

But in my navigator I have a 2002 error ...
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

But I've modified my credentials ...

```
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_INTRANET', 'silexx_dev');
define('DB_INTRANET_UTI', 'root');
define('DB_INTRANET_PWD', 'root');

$oPDO = new PDO ('mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_INTRANET, DB_INTRANET_UTI, DB_INTRANET_PWD);
$oPDO -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Honestely, I don't understand ... :s 
Have you got an idea please ?

Thanks.

Comment: Sometimes `localhost` won't work but `define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31413728/connect-mysql-through-localhost-not-working-but-127-0-0-1-is-working)

Comment: @Nigel you should look at the resolving answer: here, _inside_ a container, the hostname must be the name of the linked container. Outside the container, `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` mean the same thing, as almost every modern OS aliases `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` anyway nowadays.

Comment: @AlexRock, as OP exposes 3306 to the host in the docker-compose.yml, this should allow you to connect through the host.  Also as for the difference - https://stackoverflow.com/a/31414252/1213708 - and as the error indicates it's trying to use `'/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'` then this would show it's the issue.

Comment: Sorry @Nigel but Alex is right, then my container works.

Comment: You just needed to change it to something other than `localhost` - you can use the name of the container (as in the answer), or it's IP address, I think 127.0.0.1 should work as you expose the port to the host.

Comment: No, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must change the app's `host` database config to the name of the database container that is linked to your app.

Here, in your example, the container name is `mysql`, therefore you need this change:

```
-define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
+define('DB_HOST', 'mysql');
```